# How to get field value from firestore database in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get data from my firestore database into my react native project. I've been able to get the data of a whole collection but unsure of how I would get different field values individually. Like how would I display the values FlagQuizscore: 83.33333333333334 WalesQuizscore:80 coins:46 from my firestore database into my react native project?

This code displays the values for the whole collection :

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

export default function ModesScreen({navigation}) {
    const email = auth.currentUser.email
    const userCollectionRef = collection(db,"Users")
    const [users,setUsers] = useState([])

    useEffect(()=>{
        const getUsers = async () => {
            const data = await getDocs(userCollectionRef)
            setUsers(data.docs.map((doc)=>({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})))
        }
        getUsers()
    },[])

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {users.map((users)=>{return<View key={doc.id}>
                <Text>{users.WalesQuizscore}</Text>
                <Text>{users.coins}</Text>
            </View>})}
        </View>
    );
}
```

Results from my database I want to get into my react native project :

[image]

Comment: Which part isn't working in this case? Are you getting any errors or so?

Comment: No, It works but it is returning the whole collection when all I want is the specific field values. And I have no idea how I would do that

Comment: Are you trying to fetch a single document with given email ID and then read it's fields?

Comment: Yeah, I want it to show the user's score and coins when they're logged in. I've got it so it uploads the values to firestore just don't know how to display them once they are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to get a single document then you can use `getDoc()` function. Also no need to declares users as an array. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

export default function ModesScreen({navigation}) {
  const email = auth.currentUser.email
  const userDocRef = doc(db,"Users", email)
  const [user, setUser] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUser = async () => {
      const snap = await getDoc(userDocRef)
      setUser({email, ...snap.data()})
    }
    getUser()
  },[])

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {return <View key={user.email || 'email'}>
          <Text>{user.WalesQuizscore}</Text>
          <Text>{user.coins}</Text>
        </View>})}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that worked. Been trying to do this for a while now and was such a simple fix thanks again :)